# Mongodb aggregated query to calculate distance between 2 points

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, aggregation-framework

I'm new to mongodb. I need to calculate distance between previous-address to location and next-address to the same location and add the results, but I need to filter the documents before calculating the distances since `previous-address`, and `next-address` are not actually part of the document , I need to dynamically add them according to some conditions.
I have documents that looks like this:

```
{
"user_id" : 2274,
"preparation_time" : 86400000,
"prev_booking" : null,
"next_booking" : {
    "id" : 1310905,
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            55.2353495, 
            25.1627054
        ]
    }
}
```

So I need to add prev-address and next-address and there values will depend on `prev-booking` and `next-booking` with other conditions, and then I will use those to calculate the distances. But the issue is that `$geoNear` need to be at the first stage of the pipeline but this not possible in my case, any suggestions here?

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB supports 2d indexes and geospatial queries. Please first check [2d Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2d/) to know how to properly structure the index.

After that, you can calculate the [Euclidian distance](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/calculate-distances-using-spherical-geometry-with-2d-geospatial-indexes/) on a 2d plane with queries.

Best regards and best wishes in your future development Endeavors